# Handling categorical values in tuples to be predicted

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am building an API with a trained sklearn model. I have saved the model in .joblib format and I am loading it in the API backend before making predictions. But the problem is that my data contains categorical columns and I trained my model after one-hot-encoding these categorical columns using the `get_dummies()` method in the `pandas` library. My API receives JSON data with the values for the categorical columns without any encoding. How should I encode the tuple to be predicted before passing it through the model? Can anybody help me with this? Thank you.

The dataset I'm using has the following set of columns before and after encoding:

**Before:**

```
Index(['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 'thalach',
       'exang', 'oldpeak', 'slope', 'ca', 'thal'],
      dtype='object')
```

**After:**

```
Index(['age', 'sex', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 'thalach', 'exang','oldpeak', 'ca', 'cp_0', 'cp_1', 'cp_2', 'cp_3', 'thal_0',
       'thal_1', 'thal_2', 'thal_3', 'slope_0', 'slope_1', 'slope_2'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your get_dummies on predict

`df.reindex(columns=features, fill_value=0)`

where `features` is a list of features name